# Как лучше заполнять поля класса в PHP для VK API?

Tags: php, ооп, vkontakte-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с таким вопросом.

У меня есть некоторый базовый класс User (класс работы с пользователями) на языке PHP. Ну, содержит, например, этот класс некоторое количество полей (их порядка 30, но возьму в пример 4): ID пользователя, фамилия и имя, возраст. Единственным аргументом конструктора такого класса является userID - ID пользователя.

Теперь собственно сам вопрос. Как думаете, какой из данных вариантов наиболее удачный, либо же предложите, пожалуйста, свой:

1. Инициализация полей класса осуществляется при создании класса (скажем, из конструктора или отдельным методом).
2. Как только нужно получить, например, имя, я делаю соответствующий запрос (если честно, не знаю, как правильно это назвать), получаю имя и возвращаю его.
3. Как только нужно получить, например, имя, я вызываю метод, в котором осуществляется проверка, инициализировано ли поле firstName. Если не инициализировано, делаю запрос, инициализирую, возвращаю. В противном случае - просто возвращаю.

(таким образом, между пунктами 1-3 отличие заключается в том, что в пункте 1 я заполняю всевозможные переменные сразу, в пункте 2 - каждый раз заново получаю данные, а в пункте 3 - один раз получаю значение, сохраняю его и оперирую над ним).

P.s. возможно, скажете ни к чему это все делать, лишняя морока. Но в данный момент передо мной стоят две задачи: написать что-то свое и универсальное, чтобы я мог применять уже готовые реализации (в данном случае классы) к новым проектам, и побольше ковыряться в языке PHP, в особенности - его возможностях для реализации концепций ООП.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  Можно написать public метод который будет заполнять ваши поля, назвать его, предположим, setAttributes, в качестве аргумента ассоциативный массив имя-значение ваших полей. так вы сможете с помощью этого метода еще и менять свои поля.

2) Можно каждому полю добавить отдельно сеттеры и геттеры, это методы которые устанавливают и получают значения полей класса. Например, setId($id), getId(). Сеттерами будет оперировать метод setAttributes.

3) Проверять при получении значения поля, инициализировано ли оно, не нужно. Геттер просто возвращает текущее значение, даже если оно null. Может вам и нужно проверить поле на null.

4) Не совсем понятно про "запросы". Экземпляр класса и все его атрибуты по умолчанию хранятся в памяти, никаких запросов (к базе данных?) там нет.